# Condition in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

When a document is cancelled (row 1 from the attached Database table, BUSINESS STATE = Canceled), it is necessary to cancel the last active installment (in this case row 2 in the Database table) and display it on the UI (Table 2).

What the part of the query that is attached below does is to compare versions of the document (rows in the Database table) by REPORTED_DATE, and return the document that has the largest LOAD_DATE for a given month. This works properly when the cancelled document (row 1 in the Database table) has a reported date in the same month as the last active installment (row 2 in the Database table). Or when document cancellation occurs in the following month (for example: 2022-07). In this case, the last active installment will be cancelled.

When document cancellation occurs in the month before the last active installment (as is the case in the attached Database table), the current query will not work and will cancel the wrong installment (Table 1). Do you have any idea how to modify the query?

Database table (fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=edc0ed9f5855ad847e8fab04aaec4e6a):

```
CREATE TABLE ImplPolicy
    ([POLICY_KEY] decimal, [LOAD_DATE] datetime2, [REPORTED_DATE] datetime2, [BUSINESS_STATE] varchar(57), [OUTSTANDING_AMOUNT] decimal(15,2), [PREMIUM_BASE] decimal(15,2), [INSURANCE_PREMIUM] decimal(15,2), [CREDIT_INITIAL_VALUE] decimal(15,2), [LOAN_INSTALMENT_AMOUNT] decimal(15,2), [CURRENCY_CODE] varchar(3))
;

INSERT ImplPolicy
    ([POLICY_KEY], [LOAD_DATE], [REPORTED_DATE], [BUSINESS_STATE], [OUTSTANDING_AMOUNT], [PREMIUM_BASE], [INSURANCE_PREMIUM], [CREDIT_INITIAL_VALUE], [LOAN_INSTALMENT_AMOUNT], [CURRENCY_CODE])
VALUES
    ('2234511332', '2022-06-28 13:10:23.5000000', '2022-05-01 00:00:00.0000000', 'Cancelled', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '1000.00', '0.00', 'EUR'),
    ('2234511332', '2022-06-28 12:57:18.8066667', '2022-06-28 00:00:00.0000000', 'Active', '900.00', '900.00', '4.50', '1000.00', '42.60', 'EUR'),
    ('2234511332', '2022-06-28 12:56:50.4966667', '2022-05-31 00:00:00.0000000', 'Active', '920.00', '920.00', '4.60', '1000.00', '42.60', 'EUR')
;
```

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    implPolicy.REPORTED_DATE,
    implPolicy.BUSINESS_STATE,
    implPolicy.CREDIT_INITIAL_VALUE,
    implPolicy.OUTSTANDING_AMOUNT,
    implPolicy.INSURANCE_PREMIUM,
    implPolicy.LOAN_INSTALMENT_AMOUNT,
    implPolicy.PREMIUM_BASE,
    implPolicy.PREMIUM_RATE,
    premiumSat.CURRENCY_CODE,
FROM
    POLICY_HUB policyHub
    INNER JOIN POLICY_SAT_LATEST policySat ON policySat.POLICY_HKEY = policyHub.POLICY_HKEY
    INNER JOIN IMPL.POLICY_SAT implPolicy ON implPolicy.POLICY_HKEY = policyHub.POLICY_HKEY
    INNER JOIN ITEM_LINK itemLink ON policyHub.POLICY_HKEY = itemLink.POLICY_HKEY
    INNER JOIN ITEM_SAT itemSat ON itemLink.ITEM_HKEY = itemSat.ITEM_HKEY
    INNER JOIN PREMIUM_SAT premiumSat ON itemLink.ITEM_HKEY = premiumSat.PREMIUM_HKEY
WHERE
    policyHub.DOCUMENT_NUMBER = '111' AND
    implPolicy.LOAD_DATE = (SELECT MAX(implPolicyCheck.LOAD_DATE) FROM IMPL.POLICY_SAT implPolicyCheck WHERE implPolicy.POLICY_HKEY = implPolicyCheck.POLICY_HKEY AND FORMAT(implPolicy.REPORTED_DATE, 'yyyyMM') = FORMAT(implPolicyCheck.REPORTED_DATE, 'yyyyMM')) AND
    premiumSat.LOAD_DATE = implPolicy.LOAD_DATE AND
    DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, implPolicy.REPORTED_DATE), 0) BETWEEN
    DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, cast('2021-06-01T00:00:00' AS DATE)), 0) AND
    DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, cast('2022-06-30T00:00:00' AS DATE)), 0)
```

Table 1 (current result):

| BANK REPORTED MONTH | BUSINESS STATE | CREDIT INITIAL VALUE | OUTSTANDING LOAN AMOUNT | MONTHLY LOAN INSTALMENT | PREMIUM BASE | PREMIUM RATE | TOTAL PREMIUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 05.2022 | Cancelled | 1,000.00 RON | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.000000 | 0.00 RON |
| 06.2022 | Active | 1,000.00 RON | 900.00 RON | 42.60 RON | 900.00 RON | 0.005000 | 4.50 RON |

Table 2 (expected result):

| BANK REPORTED MONTH | BUSINESS STATE | CREDIT INITIAL VALUE | OUTSTANDING LOAN AMOUNT | MONTHLY LOAN INSTALMENT | PREMIUM BASE | PREMIUM RATE | TOTAL PREMIUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 05.2022 | Active | 1,000.00 RON | 920.00 RON | 42.60 RON | 920.00 RON | 0.005000 | 4.60 RON |
| 06.2022 | Cancelled | 1,000.00 RON | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.000000 | 0.00 RON |

Comment: A query fragment is not really helpful, please include your complete query or at least a working query that reproduces your example.

Comment: @Stu Query is edited.

Comment: It would help to put this into a [mre], i.e. a table definition and insert statements to get some mock data to work with (note that only one table is sufficient to reproduce the problem). You probably need some ROW_NUMBER() OVER clause.

Comment: We can't use the above to data to run the query. Please construct a https://dbfiddle.uk containing tables and sample data.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is a code smell, it indicates the joins are not thought through properly. `implPolicy.LOAD_DATE = (SELECT MAX(implPolicyCheck.LOAD_DATE)` could probably do with a dose of window functions. `DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, implPolicy.REPORTED_DATE), 0) BETWEEN .....` is not a good way of checking months, you are far better off doing `implPolicy.REPORTED_DATE >= CAST('2021-06-01' AS DATE) AND implPolicy.REPORTED_DATE < CAST('2022-07-01' AS DATE)`.

Comment: The table IMPL.POLICY_SAT attached to the question is used in query (I added the rest of the columns just to avoid confusion). @Charlieface Thank you for your tips for the rest of the query. I will fix that as soon as I find a solution to the problem in question.

Comment: @Charlieface Link - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=edc0ed9f5855ad847e8fab04aaec4e6a  to the table in dbfiddle.uk with the entered data. (the table is only named differently). Is that enough now?

Comment: So looks like you want something like a row-number solution https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ea518a4ea05d819cf3e113ba73af8f74

Comment: Hey @Charlieface.The last active installment should be canceled (in this case the second row in the table, where OUTSTANDING_AMOUNT = 900), and the penultimate installment should be shown on the UI(as in Table 2 (expected result))... I think that if the cancellation happened in month before the last active installment, we cannot watch REPORTED_DATE. Or if we are going to compare by REPORTED DATE, then just for comparison purposes, to change that both documents, the cancellation of the document and the last active installment, happened in the same month (it would be workaround). Thank you!

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean. The solution I gave will give all `Cancelled` rows, and the last `Active` row. It seems to match your expected result. Do you actually want to modify the rows, or do you just want to select them?

Comment: @Charlieface The problem is if we have more Active rows. All Active rows should be displayed, only the last one should be cancelled.

Comment: You are still being unclear. Do you want to select then all `Active` rows and the last `Cancelled` one, or do you want to actually modify one of the `Active` rows to be `Cancelled`?

Comment: When cancellation occurs, the **last Active row** should be modified to be **Cancelled**. @Charlieface

Comment: So something like this maybe? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2b41dddde1638991d2b77565aff4e6fe

Comment: The output should look like in Table 2 (below the question). Only one row with BUSINESS_STATE=Cancelled should be displayed.